# transpose two words as in Sublime Text

Tags: emacs, sublimetext2, emacs24

I was watching a online class of Django and the teacher did a nice trick in Sublime Text with two values of a list, it transpose each to the position of the other, for instance:

```
list = ("foo", "bar", "hello")
```

marked `foo` and `bar` with the mouse and then did the transpose, getting the following:

```
list = ("bar", "foo", "hello")
```

How that can be achieve in Emacs?

Comment: Put the cursor at `foo` and call `M-x transpose-words`

Comment: ... `transpose-words` is bound to `M-t` by default. It works without a region (i.e., you don't have to "mark" anything for it to work). To transpose `foo` and `bar`, point can be on any of the following characters: `oo", "b`. Putting it *before* them will transpose `list` and `foo`; putting it after them will transpose `bar` and `hello`.

Comment: Related commands for transposing other units of text, along with their default key bindings (if any): `transpose-chars` (`C-t`), `transpose-lines` (`C-x C-t`), `transpose-paragraphs`, `transpose-sentences`, `transpose-sexps` (`C-M-t`).

Comment: Oh, wow, awesome! Thanks! (this question needs to have a answer, any volunteer?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @artscan says, the command you are looking for is `transpose-words`. It is bound to `M-t` by default. It works without a region (i.e., you don't have to "mark" anything for it to work). To transpose `foo` and `bar`, point can be on any of the following characters:

`oo", "b`

Putting point *before* them will transpose `list` and `foo`; putting it *after* them will transpose `bar` and `hello`.

Related commands for transposing other units of text, along with their default key bindings (if any):

- `transpose-chars` (<kbd>C-t</kbd>)
- `transpose-lines` (<kbd>C-x C-t</kbd>)
- `transpose-paragraphs`
- `transpose-sentences`
- `transpose-sexps` (<kbd>C-M-t</kbd>)

#### Going Beyond Built-Ins

If you want to transpose words that are not adjacent (e.g., `foo` and `hello`) with a single keystroke, you can define a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html) or a custom command and bind it to a key:

```lisp
(defun hop-one-transpose ()
  "Transpose words that are separated by a single word."
  (interactive)
  (transpose-words 2)
  (backward-word 3)
  (forward-char)
  (transpose-words 1))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-t") 'hop-one-transpose)
```

---

#### Appendix: Let Emacs Help You Discover Emacs

If you find yourself wondering whether Emacs has a command for some type of action, try using `command-apropos` to find it:

<kbd>C-h a</kbd> `<action>` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: and what should I do if I want to transpose `foo` and `hello` with just one key stroke?

Comment: @JorgeArayaNavarro You can define a [macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html) or a custom function and bind that to a key. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: Doesn't work if one of the words inside the double quotes contains a non-word character, like a dot, e.g. `"foo.baz", "bar"`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `transpose-sexp` (rather than `transpose-words`), bound to `M-C-t`.  In some modes it understands enough of the syntax to be able to transpose `(foo (1, 2), a + b)` to (`a + b, foo (1, 2))`.  In C-mode, sadly, it would result in `(foo a, (1, 2) + b)` which is not nearly as useful.